# Require a client library installed via npm in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, npm, pug, assets

I've a problem with a nodejs app which should serve js assets to the client.
I've installed some modules using npm (primus or socket.io for example), and i want to send these js files to the browser.

Using jade and having a public folder in the root of my project is simple:

```
script(src='/js/lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js')
script(src='/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js')
```

This example loads with success to the browser the scripts below.

But how can do the same with libraries inside the node_modules folder?

Comment: maybe create a symlink? `ln -s /home/foo/project/bar/node_modules/baz.js /home/foo/project/bar/public/baz.js` or, just copy the file?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to send npm/.js files intended to be run by node to the browser, the browser will not know what to do w/ it.

For socket.io if you just do:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```

on the node/server side, where "app" is your express server, socket.io will automatically take care of serving up the appropriate browser .js files at the /socket.io/socket.io.js url.  The reason for this is that it will server up a slightly different socket.io.js file for every client.

not sure about primus.

Comment: So the server creates a route to js file via /socket.io/socket.io.js  when socket.io is initialized, right? I need to understand this :)